# View running metro apps in the 8.1 taskbar

Tags: windows-8, taskbar, modern-ui

Is it possible to see the list of currently runing metro apps in the taskbar for multitasking purposes?  Having both the taskbar, and the "metro multitask" bar is annoying for switching back and forth.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Suspend Modern UI app to taskbar](http://superuser.com/questions/491846/suspend-modern-ui-app-to-taskbar)

Comment: Perhaps also check out: http://superuser.com/questions/663554/how-can-i-easily-display-all-currently-running-metro-apps-in-windows-8?rq=1

Comment: Suspending apps (topic: memory consumption) is not the same as user interaction. I don't think the above two answers are related to the OP. The OP is asking why the two task bars exist and if this can be turned off or merged into the legacy task bar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this is currently not possible out of the box in Windows 8.1.
However, the current leaked betas of Windows 8.1 Update 1 show this functionality being added.

[image: Show Desktop apps on the taskbar]